# Can't change background of elements in aside tag html5

Tags: html, css, web

I checked my code multiple times. I can't see anything wrong with it. I can change the background of everything but the news in the aside tag. What's wrong with it? This is the css code. I called the aside tag news. My id of the aside tag is correct in html. I checked that before asking this question.

```
*{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

h1{
font: bold 20px Tahoma;
}

h2{
font: bold 14px Comic Sans MS;
}
header,section,footer,aside,article,nav,hgroup{
display:block;
}

body{
text-align:center; 
}

#whole_wrapper{
border:1px solid brown;
width: 1000px;
margin: 20px auto;
text-align: left;
background-color:orange;
}

#top_header{
background:beige;
padding: 20px;
}

#main_menu{
background:lightgreen;
color:blue;
}

#main_menu li{
display:inline-block;
list-style:none;
padding:5px;
font: bold 14px Tahoma;
}

#main_section{
float:left;
width:660px;
margin:30px;
}`  

#news{
float:left;
width:220px;
margin:20px 0px;
padding:30px;
background-color:red;
}

#bottom_footer{
clear:both;
text-align:center;
padding:20px;
border-top:2px solid beige;
}

article{
background-color:azure;
border: 1px solid navy;
padding:20p;
margin-bottom:15px;
}
```

Comment: correct the typo ( ' ) in css declaration, also, can you provide <html> code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have various typos in your CSS. Also, be sure to specify specific colors instead of declarations such as `blue` or `beige`.  Here it is cleaned up, with no edits to the colors.

```
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

h1{
    font: bold 20px Tahoma;
}

h2{
    font: bold 14px Comic Sans MS;
}
header, section, footer, aside, article, nav, hgroup{
    display:block;
}
body{
    text-align:center; 
}

#whole_wrapper{
    border:1px solid brown;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: orange; /* Use a specific color instead */
}
#top_header{
    background: beige; /* Use a specific color instead */
    padding: 20px;
}
#main_menu{
    background:lightgreen; /* Use a specific color instead */
    color:blue;
}
#main_menu li{
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    padding:5px;
    font: bold 14px Tahoma;
}
#main_section{
    float:left;
    width:660px;
    margin:30px;
}
#news{
    float:left;
    width:220px;
    margin:20px 0px;
    padding:30px;
    background-color:red; /* Use a specific color instead */
}
#bottom_footer{
    clear:both;
    text-align:center;
    padding:20px;
    border-top:2px solid beige; /* Use a specific color instead */
}
article{
    background-color:azure; /* Use a specific color instead */
    border: 1px solid navy; /* Use a specific color instead */
    padding:20p;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}
```